# Pull - Push mixins function with singularity

Tags: singularitygs, breakpoint-sass

In the singularity demo, there are a few samples using a push and pull mixin. When used they adjust content placement across the gutter. Looking high and low, I could not find any documented reference to these mixins. Are they part of the long term feature set or a leftover? If not, what is the recommended way to do this sort of gutter shift?

Found the answer [here](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/issues/161)

Answer (score 0):

Push/Pull are currently non-documented features that are being deprecated in Singularity 1.2.0. They make sense when using `float` output method and symmetric grids, but don't make sense for any other combination we can think of. Instead, we recommend utilizing the `isolation` output style (or, if you're feeling adventurous, the new [`calc`](http://snugug.com/musings/bulletproof-combo-fixed-and-fluid-grids-css3-calc) output style in Singularity Extras)

The other option is to write your own mixin with the use of the `grid-span`, `column-span`, and `gutter-span` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Having read about the deprecation of push/pull in Ver 1.2.0, I have just swapped my pull spans for isolation spans. It was so easy, I can't imagine why I hadn't used that method before. A lot of Singularitygs has to be learnt by trial and error, but perhaps the next set of docs will be better. I have also seen that they are removing the grid-overlay and grid-toggle from Ver 1.2.0. That's a shame. I got them working beautifully despite the lack of documentation. Still, the background-grid works well.